# floating layout

Tags: android, layout

Well first of all have a look at the next picture

[image]

when im trying to write something on the EditText(the red line), then the green layout is not showing anymore, I want the green layout to float so it will be always sticked to the top(like a title bar) no matter what,(the blue layout is Recyclerview and i dont mind if some of it will be hidden), and the green one is LinearLayout, how can i manage to do such a thing?

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.me.something.lolz">
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/llBanner"
    android:background="@color/colorVika"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/back"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/something_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/nBUtc"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOpti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/optie"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>







    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvholy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lala"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/llBanner"
    android:id="@+id/rvME"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/etText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/savetton"
            android:text="d"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not care if the blue layout will resize, I just care about the green layout since it has important buttons in it...

Comment: Use `adjustPan` for your activity in manifest file.

Comment: @Piyush dosent work...

Comment: @Piyush just added, i need the green layout to always be shown...

Comment: This  `android:weightSum="100"` is wrong. Second while you'r using weight then if it is for vertical linearlayout then `height` must be `0dp` and if it is horizontal layout then it `width` must be `0dp`.

Comment: @Piyush still... this should fix the issue with the top layout disapearing? how can i make it float? the outher layout dosent important at all

Answer (score 1):

Add on the next code on your activity on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        ...............
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"/>
```

or if is not works, try using:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your green layout outside of LinearLayout, it will be always appear, just put it under the root Relative Layout. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/greenLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/greenLayout"
    android:id="@+id/recyleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText" />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  />
....

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: youre example is same as what i did..... the green layout aka(llBanner at my example), is under the root. at the same way your written it.... if you can try to do it on my code and see what is the problem... since it still disapear and dosent stick to the top